# Minimum time of stable input address on read cycle of a flash chip

Tags: datasheet, flash

While reading the specifications for the SST39SF010A flash memory chip ([here](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/14f5/0900766b814f54fc.pdf)), and looking at diagram 5 and the general specifications, there is no minimum stable address input time.

Looking again at diagram 5, we can see that the output data *can* be ready before the end of the cycle. But then, if a noisy non stabilized input address comes in, must I fear of triggering a read cycle ?

Again, given the diagram it doesn't seem, but the specifications don't list that, and so I am afraid of triggering a write cycle before the input address is fully stabilized, and "wasting" 55/70 ns before creating a new. Is there a general guideline or implicit rule I'm not informed about in this case ?

I am looking forward to your answers, any help or tip is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The address setup (Tas 0ns) and address hold (Tah 30ns) times are defined in Table 12 and indicated on figure 6. They are shown for the preamble bytes but you can assume they are the same for the actual address bits. The actual write is triggered by the Write enable (or chip enable) not the address.

[image: fig6]

Comment: Sorry, but I was mainly asking for figure 6 and it's corresponding table 11, for read operations. Particularly the second read cycle shown (then one without CE# and OE# going low at the beginning). The write/erase cycle is, hopefully, well documented.